# Map annotations overlap when they should get clustered

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I'm working on an iOS swift application that displays images as annotations on a map. When multiple annotations would be overlapping they should get clustered and instead showing as one of the images.

The apple provided clustering does not work sometimes. When zooming out and in multiple times there is a chance that images are overlapping a lot.

This is how it should look:
[image: This is how it should look]

This is how it looks when the bug occurs:
[image: This is how it looks when the bug occurs]

I've uploaded a sample video to Youtube (https://youtu.be/kaI0bTS8_HY)

Some details about the implementation:

- I'm using a specialized MKAnnotationView:

  ```
  class PhotoAnnotationView: MKAnnotationView {
    let annotationWidth = 100

    var imageView = UIImageView()

    override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
      super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
      clusteringIdentifier = "LocatedPhoto"
      collisionMode = .circle

      addSubview(imageView)
      imageView.frame = annotationFrame
      frame = annotationFrame
    }

    var annotationFrame: CGRect {
      return CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: annotationWidth, height: annotationWidth)
    }

    override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
      willSet {
          if let annotation = newValue as? PhotoAnnotation {
              let url = annotation.locatedPhoto.thumbnailURL
              let displayLocation = annotation.displayLocation
              setImage(url: url)
          }
      }
    }

    func setImage(url: URL) {
      //...
    } 
  }
  ```

The MapViewController registers this annotation type for displaying annotations:

```
mapView.register(PhotoAnnotationView.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier)
```

Omitted because I think it's not the source of the problem:
 - The MKClusterView (bug also present with regular ClusterView)
 - Adding of the annotations to the map view

What could be the source of this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `PhotoAnnotationView`, your `annotation` observer should reset the `clusteringIdentifier`:

```
override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
    willSet {
        if let annotation = newValue as? PhotoAnnotation {
            clusteringIdentifier = "LocatedPhoto"            // make sure to reset this
            let url = annotation.locatedPhoto.thumbnailURL
            let displayLocation = annotation.displayLocation
            setImage(url: url)
        }
    }
}
```

As they're getting dequeued and reused, the `clusteringIdentifier` can get cleared. By setting it again, you ensure that clustering will still take place.